# pysqlite insert unicode data 8-bit bytestring error

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode

I know similar permutations of this question have been asked before, but the answers don't seem to shed light on what I am doing wrong here.

I am trying to insert this row:
    (Pdb) print row
['886', '39', '83474', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1.00', 'D', '20070813', 'R', 'C', 'B', "SOCK 4PK", '\xe9\x9e\x8b\xe5\xad\x90\xe5\xb0\xba\xe5\xaf\xb86-9.5/24-27.5CM', 'PR']

into this table:
CREATE TABLE item ("whs" int,"dept" int,"item" int,"dsun" int,"oh" int,"ohrtv" int,"adjp" int," adjn" int,"sell" text,"stat" text,"lsldt" int,"cat1" text,"cat2" text,"cat3" text,"des1" text,"sgn3" text,"unit" text);

The sgn3 column seems to causing the problems. It is defined as TEXT, and the data to be inserted is utf-8. Why am I receiving the sqlite3 error?

ProgrammingError: 'You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestr...= str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.'

Here is the code doing the insert:

```
query = 'insert into %s values(%s)' % (
    self.tablename,
    ','.join(['?' for field in row])
)
self.con.execute(query, row)
```

And here is the procedure that creates the generator of records to be inserted:

```
def encode_utf_8(self, csv_data, csv_encoding):
    """Decodes from 'csv_encoding' and encodes to utf-8.  

    Accepts any open csv file encoding using any scheme recognized by 
    python. Returns a generator.  

    """
    for line in csv_data:
        try:
            yield line.decode(csv_encoding).encode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is one of the most helpful error messages that I've ever seen. Just do what it says. Feed it `unicode` objects, not UTF-8-encoded `str` objects. In other words, lose the `.encode('utf-8')` or maybe follow that later by decode('utf-8') ...what *exactly* is `csvdata`?

If you ever get a UnicodeDecodeError in your existing code:

(1) You should do something much more useful than what you intended to do with it (sweep it under the carpet)

(2) You may wish to change `next` to `pass`

**Response to comment**

> haha, it is a very useful error
>   message

haha??? I wasn't joking; it tells you exactly what to do.

> csvdata is a csv file in this case
>   encoding using big5 in python 2.x

What are you calling "a csv file":

```
(1) csvdata = open('my_big5_file', 'rb')
(2) csvdata = csv.reader(open('my_big5_file', 'rb'))
(3) other; please specify
```

> if I chose not to encode to utf-8, my
>   rows are ascii right?

Utterly *wrong*. `bytes_read_from_file.decode('big5')` produces a `unicode` object. You may like to read [the Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-howto).

> so i need to explicitly change them to unicode before saving to the database?

No, they are `unicode` already. However depending on what `csvdata` is, you may want to encode into `utf8` to get them through the csv mechanism and then decode them later.

Comment: haha, it is a very useful error message
csvdata is a csv file in this case encoding using big5
in python 2.x if I chose not to encode to utf-8, my rows are ascii right? so i need to explicitly change them to unicode before saving to the database?